# else block does not work properly

Tags: python, if-statement

I try to create a book list in python.

Here are the sample list:

The list contains book_id, bookName, writerName, writerSurname, cost objects.

```
  books = [
     [45623, 'Ptyhon', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 23],
     [99878, 'Linux Networks', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 26],
     [98938, 'Operating Systems', 'Ali', 'Akinci', 17],
     [98947, 'PHP and AJAX', 'Haydar', 'Baskan', 25]
     ]
```

I want to search the list according to writer surname.

```
 while 1:
     writerSurname = input('Pls enter the writer's surname.')
     if writerSurname not in ['exit', 'Exit']:
         for k in books:
             if str(writerSurname) == k[3]:
                 print(k[1],'writer', k[2],k[3], "cost is", k[4],"TL")

     else:
         print(writerSurname, 'there is no such a person.')
         break
```

But else block does not work properly. When I type a surname which is not in book list, it does not show print(writerSurname, 'there is no such a person.') line. Can someone advise where I do make a mistake ?

Comment: `writerSurname = input('Pls enter the writer's surname.')` is not valid syntax.

Comment: this code cannot work, because of the single quote in the input prompt.

Comment: `input('Pls enter the writer's surname.')` would certainly throw an error. Use `"` or escape the `'`.

Comment: the `else` statement is related to the `if writerSurname` statement. and syntax highlighting in SO code snippet shows you clearly that your code cannot work because of the stray quotechar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indentation errors and some logical errors. All the mayhem in your code aren't necessarily required so I simplified the code to the following:

```
books = [
     [45623, 'Ptyhon', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 23],
     [99878, 'Linux Networks', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 26],
     [98938, 'Operating Systems', 'Ali', 'Akinci', 17],
     [98947, 'PHP and AJAX', 'Haydar', 'Baskan', 25]
     ]

while True: 
    surname = input("pls enter the writer's surname: ") 
    for record in books:
        if surname in record:
            print("..details..")
            break 
    else: 
        print("Failed")
```

Note: If you're dealing with details/records like names, numbers and these details are related and you believe you'll be constantly searching for these details, I find it more convenient to use dictionaries, faster than searching linearly in a list.

The `while` loop is to allow multiple entries for you program, so you can enter infinite number of names to your program. The inner `for` loop does the actual job, searching in your embedded lists to find the surname if it exists. If a surname is found, `print("...details...")` will be executed, if all the embedded lists were searched but no matching surname was found then `print("Failed")` will be executed.

Hope this helps and good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the invalid syntax, the `if` statement does not concern whether or not the surname is in the book list: The only thing you are checking is whether or not one types exit/Exit.

Answer (score 1):

for any input not in book list, the code goes into `if` block when input is not "exit" or "Exit".

This is the correct version:

```
books = [
    [45623, 'Ptyhon', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 23],
    [99878, 'Linux Networks', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 26],
    [98938, 'Operating Systems', 'Ali', 'Akinci', 17],
    [98947, 'PHP and AJAX', 'Haydar', 'Baskan', 25]
]

while 1:
    writerSurname = raw_input('Pls enter the writers surname.')
    if writerSurname not in ['exit', 'Exit']:
        found = False
        for k in books:
            if str(writerSurname) == k[3]:
                print(k[1],'writer', k[2],k[3], "cost is", k[4],"TL")
                found = True
        if not found:
            print(writerSurname, 'there is no such a person.')
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

the inner loop should use a flag set if some name matches

```
while True:
     writerSurname = input("Pls enter the writer's surname.")
     if writerSurname in ['exit', 'Exit']:
         break
     found = False
     for k in books:
         if writerSurname == k[3]:
             found = True
             print(k[1],'writer', k[2],k[3], "cost is", k[4],"TL")
     if not found:
         print(writerSurname, 'there is no such a person.')
         break
```

Note that for a single breaking match (not applicable here), you could use the `for/else` statement:

```
 for k in books:
     if writerSurname == k[3]:
         print(k[1],'writer', k[2],k[3], "cost is", k[4],"TL")
         break
 else:
     # end of the loop reached, without break: enters here
     print(writerSurname, 'there is no such a person.')
```

Comment: your comment seems good but there are 2 books belongs to Mustafa Basar. In your code, it only show the first one, the second one are not printed.

Comment: second snippet is not applicable here. but I was mentionning it because it's lesser known and sometimes avoids the use of a flag (not here).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
books = [
     [45623, 'Ptyhon', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 23],
     [99878, 'Linux Networks', 'Mustafa', 'Basak', 26],
     [98938, 'Operating Systems', 'Ali', 'Akinci', 17],
     [98947, 'PHP and AJAX', 'Haydar', 'Baskan', 25]
 ]

surnames = [book[3].lower() for book in books]

while 1:
    writerSurname = input("Pls enter the writer's surname.").lower()
    if writerSurname in surnames:
        for _, book_name, author_name, author_surname, cost in books:
            if author_surname.lower() == writerSurname:
                print("{book_name} writer {author_name} {author_surname} cost is {cost} TL".format(book_name=book_name, author_name=author_name, author_surname=author_surname, cost=cost))
    else:
        print(writerSurname, 'there is no such a person.')
        if writerSurname == 'exit':
            break
```